# Add different Textfield in TableViewCell and puts different Values on different Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]
I can add Seven textfield in tableViewCell with set different tag value using storyboard.when enter value in first cell textfield those value can be show on tableview other cells. But i can enter different different value on different textfield of cell. I can use tableview like excel sheet. 
Tag value set by all textfield using storyboard and need to set tag value value by programatically?

Code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableViews{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 100;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_dairyTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    tableView.allowsSelection=NO;

  UITextField *textFieldName = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row+100];
    NSString *text = [textFieldName text];
    NSLog(@"%@",text);

//    UITextField *textFieldworkLocation = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
//    UITextField *textFieldPrice = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
//    UITextField *textFieldMeasuredWork = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:4];
//    UITextField *textFieldOwnSnags = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:5];
//    UITextField *textFieldRework = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:6];
//    UITextField *textFieldOthers = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:7];
    return cell;
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([textField tag]-100) inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *Cell = [_dairyTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",Cell);
}
```

Comment: please do clear what you want to do so i gives you specific solution ?

Comment: Seven Textfields set in tableview cell. put values in textfields of first cell.than      second cell put different value and so on.This type handle textfields on tableview..But problem is put value on first cell textfields those value show other cells

Comment: did you get right cell in textFieldDidEndEditing method ?

Answer (score 1):

As you see from the `storyboard` there will be only 1 `UITextField` and your cells are generated by `reuseCell property` so if you give `tag` from `storyboard` then every `UITextField` have the same `tag` and you never distinct between them. So give `Tag` at run time in `cellForRow` as follow:

```
//and if you creating UITextfield in `uiTableView` then you have to create new custom  `UITableViewcell`

cell.textField.tag = indexpath.row
```

**How to deal `UITextField` Value :**

1. First of all you have to create mutable Array with count equal to the number of `UITextField`.
2. Initially, array have each data in empty. (Assign like this `arrDataText = ["","",... so on]`).
3. Save every `UITextField`value in the array in the same sequence with each character change. So, do code in `textdidChange` delegate method of `UITextField`.
4. Whenever user enters or edit the text, you get that text in dictionary.
5. Now in `cellForRow` add below line:

`cell.textfiled.text = arrDataText[index.row]`

Comment: First textfield Value show on Tenth and other textfield value

Comment: @DEEPAKkumar Not getting you

Answer (score 0):

use property "tag" .

```
UITextField *textFieldName = [UITextField new];
textFieldName.tag = indexPath.row;
```